# Remove zeros and insert a dash (-) between numbers in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I have a string column 7 characters in length and I am tasked with modifying it to remove  zeros and adding a dash between non zero numbers. Example below:

0022012 -- > 22-12

0018000 -- > 18-0

I've tried the scan function, but it doesn't seem to ignore the 0's

```
data abc;
set table;
do I = 1 to 7;
id = scan(var1,i,'-','0');
if missing(id) then leave;
output;
end;
```

Comment: Is the 5th character always a 0?

Comment: How many numbers to you expect to find in the 7 digit strings?  Is it always exactly two? 
 Is that why '0018000' translates to '18-0' instead of just '18'?

Comment: @Tom the last digit needs to be captured, whether it's 0 or not. It's a big list, but I see cases where there are 4 digits present, such as 21-13

Comment: @StuSztukowski no, example 0001110  needs to be converted to 1-110  and now I'm realizing this is even more complicated

Comment: What rule would convert '00001110' to '1-110'? Why not '0-1110'? Or '11-10' or '111-0'?  Is it just the first 5 and the last 3 converted to numbers and concatenated?

Comment: @Tom case list from outside source, trying to understand why they have it formatted this way, but I'm assuming the last 3 digits need to be captured unless 0 is the leading number, in which case it needs to be left out

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the pattern is SSSSEEE in which case you can just convert to numbers and use CATX() to generate the string you want.

Let's try an example:

```
data have;
  input string $7. ;
cards;
0022012
22-12
0018000
18-0
0001110
1-110
;

data want;
  set have;
  length id $8 ;
  if indexc(string,'-') then id=string;
  else id=catx('-',input(string,4.),input(substr(string,5),3.));
run;
```

Result

```
Obs    string      id

 1     0022012    22-12
 2     22-12      22-12
 3     0018000    18-0
 4     18-0       18-0
 5     0001110    1-110
 6     1-110      1-110
```

Or you could convert the 's-e' strings into SSSSEEE strings instead.

```
data want;
  set have;
  length id $7 ;
  if not indexc(string,'-') then id=string;
  else id=put(input(scan(string,1,'-'),7.),Z4.)||put(input(scan(string,2,'-'),7.),Z3.);
run;
```

Comment: you are the man sir

Comment: may I ask you what SSSSEEE stands for?

Comment: Just using two different letters to indicate which digits go together.